# sql server trigger for insert new record

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a table called 'tblDive' with columns:

```
create table tblDive (
DiveNumber int
InstructorNumber int
ClubNumber int
InstructorSigniture date
)
```

and another table:

```
create table tblWorksAt (
InstructorNumber int
ClubNumber int
StartWorkingDate date
EndWorkingDate date
)
```

the table 'tblWorksAt' has this record:

```
InstructorNumber | ClubNumber | StartWorkingDate | EndWorkingDate
       1               2            1.1.2000          1.1.2005
```

i want to create a trigger that checks when inserting a new dive, if the instructor really worked at this club in the same time of signing on the dive.
so for example if i insert a new dive:

```
insert into tblDive (DiveNumber InstructorNumber ClubNumber InstructorSigniture) 
values 111, 1, 2, 1.1.2009
```

i won't be able to insert this record because instructor number 1 stopped working at club number 2 in 1.1.2005

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how do i write this trigger!?

Comment: Can't you just set `InstructorNumber` column to be unique?

Comment: @Hoh I don't see how that would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Brandon he won't be able to add a new row with that value, if I understood well that is the problem he wants to solve, right?

Comment: @Hoh I think the problem the OP wants to solve is to ensure that the instructor is still employed. Surely an employed instructor can have multiple dives?

Comment: @jpw seems like I misunderstood the question since he wrote that he shouldn't be able to insert a new record because instructor number 1 stopped working etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using a trigger is to use a check constraint and a user defined function.

A function that checks is the instructor is employed at the right club at the right time:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckEmployment(@InstructorNumber int, @ClubNumber int, @checkdate date)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
        SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) 
        FROM tblWorksAt 
        WHERE InstructorNumber = @InstructorNumber 
        AND ClubNumber = @ClubNumber
        AND (EndWorkingDate IS NULL OR EndWorkingDate > @checkdate)
   RETURN @retval
END;
GO
```

And a check constraint using it:

```
ALTER TABLE tblDive 
ADD CONSTRAINT chkEmployed 
CHECK (dbo.CheckEmployment(InstructorNumber, ClubNumber, InstructorSigniture) != 0);
```

This might not be the most efficient way, but it should get the job done. The logic in the function might need improvement too, I might have missed something.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84e196/1) showing it in action.

Comment: How would this scale to bulk inserts?  Wouldn't the function execute N times?  Also, can check constraints execute functions and query other tables?  I didn't think that was possible, but I suppose I never tried.  It surprised me to see that.

Comment: @Brandon I have no idea how it would scale, probably poorly for the reason you suggested, but yes, checks can execute functions, so this approach should work (and it does on my test server).

Comment: Sweet, I love when I learn something.  I'd still caution the OP that this might not scale well if you do a bulk insert of hundreds of thousands of rows at a time.

Comment: @Brandon According to the docs: _By default, constraints are ignored during a bulk-import operation that is performed by the bcp command or BULK INSERT statement._ so I guess performance shouldn't be a problem, but at the loss of integrity as it would be possible to insert bad data.

Answer (score 0):

What I'll do is give you some hints and not-so-obvious information about triggers that may help you write the trigger, but *you* need to write it.

**The `inserted` table**

In SQL Server triggers, there are 2 pseudo-tables that you can reference: `inserted` and `deleted` tables.  The names are somewhat deceiving, particularly if you are doing an `UPDATE`.  The thing to remember is that under the hood, an `UPDATE` is a delete plus insert.

So essentially, `inserted` is the new (or updated) rows and `deleted` is the deleted rows and/or previous rows from an UPDATE before the changes were applied.

For a straight `INSERT` statement, the `deleted` table ought to be empty.

Therefore, you want to look for rows in `inserted` that meet a certain set of criteria.  There are two logical ways to approach this:

1. Check if all rows meet this condition
2. Look for any rows that do *not* meet the condition.

**Join**

If you join `inserted` to `tblWorksAt`, you now have all the data you need.  Something like this to join the tables and find rows that pass your business rules:

```
select 1
from inserted i
inner join tblWorksAt wa on wa.InstructorNumber = i.InstructorNumber and i.ClubNumber = wa.ClubNumber
where i.InstructorSignature between wa.StartWorkingDate and wa.EndWorkingDate
```

**What to do with the query**

Like I said before:

1. Check if all rows meet this condition
2. Look for any rows that do *not* meet the condition.

To check if all rows pass that criteria, you could:

1. Check if the count of rows matching that query equals the number of total rows in `inserted`, without a join.
2. Loop over each row in `inserted` which I will tell you right now, is almost never a good idea in a trigger.

To check if at least one row fails to pass the criteria, you could:

1. Change the `between` to `not between` and wrap this query around `if (exists(...))`.
2. Change the `inner join` to `left outer join`, move the where clause to the join, and then add a new WHERE clause that says `tblWorksAt.InstructorNumber is null`, then wrap this query around `if (exists(...))`.

**Throwing an error**

Now you know how to find rows that pass or fail.  Now you just need to throw an error to prevent the statement from completing and prevent the data from persisting.  I will leave that as an exercise to you.  It should be easy to research.